# Go build process seems to erroneously infer the wrong version of Go:

Tags: go, github, package

I have built a simple library to run a pool of workers in Go and a file (to test it) which uses said library, (see code hereunder).

When I use the local version of the library (stored in $GOROOT/src/...), using:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    . "go_parallel"

)
```

it works fine, but when I use my copy stored on GitHub, using:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    . "github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel"
)
```

I get the error message:

```
sergehulne@Serges-Mac-mini parallel_2 % go build                                 
# github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:7:23: type parameter requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:7:25: undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:7:54: type instantiation requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:9:13: type parameter requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:9:15: undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:14:19: type parameter requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:14:21: undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)
../../../../go/bin/pkg/mod/github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel@v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c/parallel.go:14:67: type instantiation requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
```

go.mod:

```
module x

go 1.18

require github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel v0.0.0-20220325154855-13fe54ffe85c // indirect
```

Go version:

```
go version go1.18 darwin/arm64
```

Library

```
package go_parallel

import (
    "sync"
)

type ParallelCallback[T any] func(chan T, chan Result[T], int, *sync.WaitGroup)

type Result[T any] struct {
    Id    int
    Value T
}

func Run_parallel[T any](n_workers int, in chan T, out chan Result[T], Worker ParallelCallback[T]) {
    go func() {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        defer close(out) // close the output channel when all tasks are completed
        for id := 0; id < n_workers; id++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go Worker(in, out, id, &wg)
        }
        wg.Wait() // wait for all workers to complete their tasks *and* trigger the -differed- close(out)
    }()
}
```

Code using said library

```
// Example of use

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    //. "go_parallel"
    . "github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel"
)

// Example of use:
const (
    NW         = 8
    BufferSize = 1
)

func Worker(in chan int, out chan Result[int], id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for item := range in {
        item *= 2 // returns the double of the input value (Bogus handling of data)
        out <- Result[int]{Id: id, Value: item}
    }
}

func main() {

    // in and out channels:
    in := make(chan int, BufferSize)
    out := make(chan Result[int])

    // Populate in channel (send data to input stream)
    go func() {
        defer close(in)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            in <- i
        }
    }()

    // Run tasks (Worker func) in parallel:
    Run_parallel(NW, in, out, Worker)

    // Display results:
    for item := range out {
        fmt.Printf("From out [%d]: %d\n", item.Id, item.Value)
    }
    println("- - - All done - - -")
}
```

Basically my question is : Why does the build process assume a version of go which appears to vary depending upon whether I use a local copy or a remote copy (gitHub) of the same code?

Comment: A module is only compatible with version of go equal to or less than the declared version in `go.mod`. You cannot build a go1.16 module with go1.18 features. Testing a version in `$GOROOT/src/` is definitely not using modules correctly, you should never have any external packages in `GOROOT`, nor should you be using `GOPATH` with modules.

Comment: "As of the Go 1.17 release, if the [go directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) is missing, go 1.16 is assumed."

Comment: `github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel` is not in a module, so go1.16 must be assumed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

The source files require a go.mod file of their own (to wrap the packages in a common module). One of its purposes is to specify the go version used by the library.

In this instance go 1.18 is required because go_parallel uses generics.

Originally, the client module `module x` specified `go 1.18` in its go.mod file, but the code using generics in the github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel repo did not have a module, and hence it defaulted to `go 1.16` as described by JimB in comment above.

The solution was to add a `go.mod` file to the github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel repo, and make sure it specified `go 1.18`. go.mod content:

```
module github.com/serge-hulne/go_parallel

go 1.18
```